# How can I query only one instance of a label?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Let's say I have the following metricand I am only interested in the value of labelTwo which is the same for all three of these.

```
metric1{labelOne="foo",labelTwo="barfoo"}
metric1{labelOne="bar",labelTwo="barfoo"}
metric1{labelOne="foobar",labelTwo="barfoo"}
```

If I query `metric1{labelTwo="barfoo"}`, then I get all three back. How can I query such that I only get one of these back?

For some context, I am writing a Prometheus query in Grafana and displaying some data related to `labelTwo`:

```
metric1{labelOne=~"$labelOne",labelTwo=~"labelTwo"}
```

The issue is that the query returns all three so I get duplicate visualizations on the dashboard when I'm really only interested in `labelTwo="barfoo"`. I want to query such that I only get one instance of `labelTwo`.

Comment: Why not just set `labelOne` to a fixed value?

Comment: The labels are dynamic so I won't know what to fix ```labelOne``` to.

Comment: Sry but I still don't understand. If you want to see only 1 time series instead of 3 you either have to filter so that you end up with a single series or you aggregate them together for example with `sum()` or `avg()`, generally. There are also functions like `topk` but people cannot recommend you the right thing without knowing more about your use case

Comment: You're right. I tried something like ```avg by (labelTwo) (metric1)``` and I got what I wanted. If you want to write an answer, I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see only 1 time series instead of 3 you either have to filter so that you end up with a single series or you aggregate them together for example with sum() or avg(), generally.